# I need to add tag to the text of pager has no tag

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add "1" on tag " in the same order
![I need to add "1" on tag " in the same order "][1]

```
<tr class="grid-pager">
      <td colspan="9">1
          <a href="/HrRequests?page=2">2</a> 
          <a href="/HrRequests?page=3">3</a> 
          <a href="/HrRequests?page=4">4</a> 
          <a href="/HrRequests?page=5">5</a> 
          <a href="/HrRequests?page=2">»</a> 
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr class="grid-pager">
    <td colspan="9">
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=1">1</a> 
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=2">2</a> 
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=3">3</a> 
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=4">4</a> 
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=5">5</a> 
        <a href="/HrRequests?page=2">»</a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

You missed the < a href... from the first tag.

Answer (score 0):

The code generated "1" without  tag ... 
we need to add tag to "1"

```
to will be <span>1</span> from <td colspan="9"> 1 ....
```